# Labelling using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

i want to label a point layer with those values exceeding a set of variables

attribute table as follows

```
'loc field'(text),'a'(float),'b'(float),'c'(float)
```

variables as follows

```
vara = 5, varb = 3, varc=1
```

basically i want to be able to label `'a' > vara, 'b' > varb, 'c' > varc` on a multi-line label, needs to label if any are true not just all three
e.g

```
Loc: F23
a: 6
```

('b' was 2 so not labelled)

```
c: 1.5
```

If none are true then loc not labelled at all

I am thinking this will be best achieved using the expression based label with a python function but don't know how to go about it, as i haven't found any documentation that deals directly with this. Could someone point me in the right direction on how to write a function that takes in each field to be queried and returns the multi-line label.

Comment: Labeling your point layer based on an expression built **only** with the Field Calculator functions would be useful for you? Or you are looking for a solely, pure Python solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function I used recently setting an expression based label on a layer.

```
def setupLabels(self):
        layerMatr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(LOOKUP_TABLE_MATR)[0]
        palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
        palyr.readFromLayer(layerMatr)

        #self.log('palyr.getLabelExpression().dump(): %s' % palyr.getLabelExpression().dump())

        palyr.fieldName = 'CASE WHEN \"MATRNR\" != \'%s\' THEN \'Matr. nr. \' || MATRNR END' % self.Ifu.Matrnr
        palyr.writeToLayer(layerMatr)
        self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

        #self.log('palyr.getLabelExpression().dump(): %s' % palyr.getLabelExpression().dump())
```